# Retornar resultado php para javascript

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Estou fazendo a requisição POST por AJAX:

HTML FORM (administracao.php):

```
<form align="center" width="50" name="excluir_documento" id="excluir_documento" onClick='return confirma_excluir_documento()' method="POST"> 
<input type="text" name="prefixo" id='prefixo' hidden value="DE"></a>
<input type="text" name="sequencial" id='sequencial' hidden value="310"></a>
<input type="text" name="nome_conf" id='nome_conf' hidden value=""></a>
<input type='submit' name='excluir_documento' id='excluir_documento' value='' class='imgExcluir' title='Excluir' ></a>
```

Javascript (funcoes.js):

```
function confirma_excluir_documento() {
            vex.defaultOptions.className = 'vex-theme-default';
            vex.dialog.confirm({
                message: 'Você irá excluir o documento. Deseja continuar?',
                callback: function(resultado) {
                    if (resultado) {
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "excluir.php",
                            data:{
                                prefixo : $("#prefixo").val(),
                                sequencial : $("#sequencial").val(),
                                nome_conf : $("#nome_conf").val(),
                                excluir_documento : 1
                            },
                            success: function (response) {
                                vex.dialog.alert('response');
                            }
                        }); 
                    }
                }
            });
                return false;
        }
```

Opós o envio a pagina php excluir.php:

```
if(isset($_post['excluir_documento']))...
... if($excluir_resultado){
echo "Documento excluído com sucesso";} 
else{
echo "Erro ao excluir";}
```

O problema que preciso do retorno de o que aconteceu com a query do banco, preciso dar o resultado dentro da caixa de dialogo `success: function (response){ vex.dialog.alert('response') ;}`, o problema que a informação que vem e de toda a pagina, desformatando a caixa de dialogo.

Como faço para pegar somente a parte `echo "Documento excluído com sucesso";}`? 
Já tentei de varias formas mais não consegui, procurei a tarde toda uma solução e nada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inicialmente a página de exclusão não necessita de nenhum retorno extra, senão a confirmação da exclusão, ou não. Portanto um 1 para "excluído" e 0 para "não excluído" já seria suficiente. Poste o código dela para poder te ajudar melhor.

Com o retorno do valor booleano, você pode efetuar o tratamento com um "If" e definir a resposta que desejar dentro do elemento HTML5 que precisar.

Usando, por exemplo, a função "ajax()" do JQuery você pode tratar os eventos das requisições, bem como trabalhar muitas outras opções.

(Veja em : http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

```js
var menuId = $( "ul.nav" ).first().attr( "id" );
//pega a variavel, monta o objeto e faz o pedido
var request = $.ajax({
  url: "excluir.php",
  method: "POST",
  data: { id : menuId },
  dataType: "html"
});

//se ok com a requisição, trata o resultado (exluido sim ou não)
request.done(function( msg ) {
  $( "#retorno" ).html( msg ); //coloca o resultado dentro do container "#log"
});
 
//caso a requisiçao falhe
request.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
  alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus ); //alerta do erro
});
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Abraço.

UPDATE//

Seu codigo do excluir.php irá se parecer com isso:

```html
<?php
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db('mydb');

/* isso retornara o numero correto de linhas excluidas se houver mais de 1 */
mysql_query('DELETE FROM mytable WHERE id < 10');
printf("Registros excluídos: %d\n", mysql_affected_rows());

/* se for somente uma linha, retonará sempre 0 */
mysql_query('DELETE FROM mytable WHERE 0');
printf("Registros excluídos: %d\n", mysql_affected_rows());
?>
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, andei procurando sobre esse tratamento de requisições do JQuery, mais não entendi muito bem. Como irei dar esse retorno depois de executar e tratar a `query` do banco? Já tentei `echo ?><script>return resposta_banco();</script><?php` para chamar uma função com a caixa de diálogo, mais nem da tempo de executar a função porque a pagina somente corre o código e já fecha.

Comment: Quando você executa uma query no MySQL com PHP, ele retorna um valor com o número de linhas afetadas. Você pode usar isso como base.
Se deletar 1, ele retorna que uma linha foi afetada. 2, "2 linhas afetadas", Assim por diante.

Comment: Você vai retornar texto puro, com ECHO ou PRINTF. ;)
O JavaScript você faz no lado cliente.

Comment: Deu certo aqui, eu até tinha achado outra solução que obtem o mesmo resultado, mas seu código fica mais objetivo. Obrigado, agora uma pequena duvida. Como faço para enviar esta requisição atraves de classe e função php até o código de exclusão?

Comment: William, tente me descrever melhor o que você quer que o procedimento faça, assim posso me orientar melhor em lhe ajudar.
Qual os paços? O que você deseja que o sistema faça.
Abraço.

Comment: Consegui já, Obrigado

Comment: Valeu!

*paços = passos (corretor se metendo! rs)

Comment: Fiz o que me passou, mais tinha informações que somente conteriam no php, precisaria deste retorno para exibir na msg do alert. Será que variável global resolveria?